# How to add custom object in apex class

Tags: apex

I have created a custom object called patient1..but I am getting error as to use __c for custom object. what mistake I have done in this program?

```
public class patient1display
{
 list<patient1__c> patient1list=new list<patient1__c>();
 public patient1display()
 {
  patient1list.clear();
  for(patient1 p : [select id,email_id__c,phone_number__c from patient1])
  {
   patient1list.add(p);
  }
 }
  public list<patient1> getpatient1()
  {
    return patient1list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the API, the names of custom objects are identified by a suffix of two underscores immediately followed by a lowercase “c” character. For example, a custom object labeled “MyObj” in the Salesforce user interface is seen as MyObj__c in that organization's WSDL.
So in your case you need to refer your object as patient1__c.

```
public class patient1display
{
 list<patient1__c> patient1list=new list<patient1__c>();
 public patient1display()
 {
  patient1list.clear();
  for(patient1__c p : [select id,email_id__c,phone_number__c from patient1__c])
  {
   patient1list.add(p);
  }
 }
  public list<patient1__c> getpatient1()
  {
    return patient1list;
  }
}
```